# Spring upgrade 4.x to 5.3.x, No connection holder avaliable

Tags: java, spring

Getting no connection holder available error, is their any change for TransactionProxyFactoryBean in spring 5, using apache ojb as orm

```
**<bean id="testBean" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <ref bean="TestTarget"/>
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
            <prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
        <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
        <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
        <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>**


**java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConnectionHolder available**
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.JdbcTransactionObjectSupport.getConnectionHolder(JdbcTransactionObjectSupport.java:76) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springmodules.orm.ojb.PersistenceBrokerTransactionManager$PersistenceBrokerTransactionObject.isRollbackOnly(PersistenceBrokerTransactionManager.java:230) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: Have you tried creating one yourself?

Comment: I didn't get what should I create? do you mean connection holder?

Comment: Yes, of course, that’a what is gone missing. The [Spring 5 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x) doesn’t mention anything in specific, so, if I were you, I’d compare how a connection holder was created in the previous version vs now in Spring source code.

Comment: `org.springmodules` does that even support Spring 5?

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't found any stuff from spring documentation/blogs saying org.springmodules is not supported.

Comment: Ofcourse not as it is impossible to state which software uses spring nor to list everything. That should be on the `org.springmodules` website and I doubt that it is compatible with Spring 6. I'm actually surprised it even worked so far as the project has been abandoned for over 15 years already. So I would simply ditch the usage of it all together.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the very old (I would say ancient) Spring Modules (supersedes in 2008 by Spring Extensions, which have since also been deprecated). See this [original Spring Forum thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20120705101424/http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?67698-An-introduction-to-Spring-Extensions) (Thanks to Wayback machine).

I'm actually surprised it did work for so long as it has been deprecated/out of support for 15+ years. [Spring Extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120620185027/http://www.springsource.org/extensions) was abandoned not much after that (or at least not many releases have taken place). The last version released was tested and compiled with Spring 2.0.3, hence my surprise it still worked. The fact that it worked is an attest to the work from the Spring Team to keep it (if possible) backwards compatible.

The [list of Spring Extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618232857/http://www.springsource.org/extensions/list) shows some of which have been abandoned and others have been integrated into parts of the portfolio themselves (like Spring Security, Spring Integration or Spring Data). Others where simply to niche and have been abandoned.

So I would suggest to simply ditch Spring Modules as there is no version that will support your current technology stack. I'm not sure what you are using but it seems something JPA/Hibernate related and I suspect that has been superseded and improved on by one of the Spring Data modules.

You are also using some old (again ancient I would say) Apache OJB technology which hasn't seen updates in 18 years. Spring (and the whole community) have abandoned the effort to work with JDO as not many where using them.

I would suggest to migrate to a modern industry standard like JPA instead of the old stuff you are using now.